# continuously reading from exec.Cmd output

Tags: go, exec, stdout

Guys I am trying pick new lines as they come from command output, but always I end up doing it synchronous way (I have to wait until script is finished). I tired to use fsnotify but it is working only with regular files, do you have any idea how it can be done ?

```
package main
import (
   "fmt"
   "os/exec"
   "bytes"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   cmd := exec.Command("scripts/long_script")
   output := new(bytes.Buffer)
   cmd.Stdout = output
   cmd.Stderr = output
   if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil{ // after Start program is continued and script is executing in background
     fmt.Printf("Failed to start " + err.Error())
     os.Exit(1)
   }
   fmt.Printf(" Before WAIT %s \n", output.String())  // script is writing but nothing can be read from output
   cmd.Wait()
   fmt.Printf(" After Wait %s \n", output.String())  // if we wait to finish execution, we can read all output
}
```

Comment: You can use `cmd.StdoutPipe` and `cmd.StderrPipe` to get the command output over pipes, which you can read as the data comes in. If you want to read them simultaneously, you'll need to set up goroutines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

eventually I managed to do it with []bytes

```
stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
buff := make([]byte,10)
var n int
for err == nil {
    n,err = stdout.Read(buff)
    if n > 0{
        fmt.Printf("taken %d chars %s",n,string(buff[:n]))
    }
}
cmd.Wait()
if cmd.ProcessState.Success() {. // ProcessState is set after Wait
    fmt.Println("Script success")  
} else {
    fmt.Println("Script failed")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use os.StdoutPipe()

```
func main() {
    for i := 10; i < 20; i++ {
        go printName(`My name is Bob, I am ` + strconv.Itoa(i) + ` years old`)
        // Adding delay so as to see incremental output
        time.Sleep(60 * time.Millisecond)
    }
    // Adding delay so as to let program complete
    // Please use channels or wait groups
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}

func printName(jString string) {
    cmd := exec.Command("echo", "-n", jString)
    cmdReader, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(cmdReader)
    go func() {
        for scanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        }
    }()
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

sources that helped me:
[nathanleclaire.com](https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/12/29/shelled-out-commands-in-golang/) 
[blog.kowalczyk.info](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/wOYk/advanced-command-execution-in-go-with-osexec.html)