# Streaming exec.Command StdoutPipe

Tags: shell, go

I'm trying to stream the Stdout of a shell command to the console, but am having difficulty.

Here's what I currently have:

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", `for number in {0..10}; do echo "$number "; done;`)
pipe, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
reader := bufio.NewReader(pipe)
line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
for err == nil {
    fmt.Println(line)
    line, err = reader.ReadString('\n')
}
```

I would expect this to print out the numbers 0 through 10, but it seems to hang on line 3 (the first call to `ReadString`.

I started with `cmd.Output()` and `cmd.CombinedOutput()`, but those methods seem to buffer the entire output stream until the command is complete. I need to process the output as it streams, not wait until the command is complete.

I also tried this: [continuously reading from exec.Cmd output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635611/continuously-reading-from-exec-cmd-output), but it didn't seem to work and I went away from it because I really want to read lines and not have to manage the buffer manually.

Other things I've looked through:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/0xK_IHbHPUU
- https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/
- https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/

Comment: Presumably you're trying to do something more complicated than this, but if you really only want to copy the command's output to stdout, simply assign os.Stdout to cmd.Stdout.

Comment: I was doing something more complicated than that, but I appreciate the tip! Thanks!

Comment: @Peter could you please post your comment as an answer? I came here searching for the same issue and I think your comment is actually the answer I seek

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to [start](https://godoc.org/os/exec#Cmd.Start) the command:

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", `for number in {0..10}; do echo "$number "; done;`)
pipe, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
   // handle error
}
reader := bufio.NewReader(pipe)
line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
for err == nil {
    fmt.Println(line)
    line, err = reader.ReadString('\n')
}
```

Call [Wait](https://godoc.org/os/exec#Cmd.Wait) after reaching EOF.

The Output and CombinedOutput methods worked for you because these methods call Start internally.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight variation on the answer from cerise-limón, but I needed the output to stream to the console as it appears. In addition, my command never produced an EOF.

Wrapping the buffer read in a go routine allows it to continue pumping output to the console while `cmd.Wait()` waits for the command to complete. Since `Wait` closes the `StdoutPipe`, it will cause `reader.ReadString` to error once the command is complete, exiting the routine.

```
cmd := exec.Command(someCommand, someArg)
pipe, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
go func(p io.ReadCloser) {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(pipe)
    line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    for err == nil {
        fmt.Println(line)
        line, err = reader.ReadString('\n')
    }
}(pipe)

if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: do you know why your command never returned EOF? Was it just a very long running command and you wanted to stream the output before it completed, or even after the command completed it still did not return EOF?