# Error in reading the byte - read |0: file already closed in go

Tags: go, exec

```
cmd := exec.Command(Args[0], Args[1])
stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
cmd.Start()
oneByte := make([]byte, 100)
num := 1
for {
    _, err := stdout.Read(oneByte)
    fmt.Println("Error read:", err)
    if err != nil {
        if err == io.EOF {
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Error stream:", err)
        }
        break
    }
```

Error in reading the byte and error message is |0: file already closed in go.

Comment: What are the values of the errors you are ignoring? (also, you cannot use `Read` without the first return value, and you should use bytes returned before checking the error)

Comment: Do you have any reference links or samples for your comment (reading the bytes). In my case i need to get the realtime output for a shell command in golang.

Comment: The [`io.Reader` documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader) covers all the details.

Comment: You may find additional info on how to use the output from StdoutPipe() here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723308/streaming-exec-command-stdoutpipe

Also, you may get `|0: file already closed in go` in case your command could not be executed at all, e.g. command does not exist.

You can use `cmd.Output()` to debug your program.

Comment: Don't ignore errors in Go.  You're not saving time deferring error management, you're wasting time because you don't know whether your program state is valid.  Can you make your behavior reproducible by hard coding a command and argument that demonstrates your behavior?  Ideally something that would work in the go playground?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `os/exec` doesn't work well on playground, but this works locally: https://go.dev/play/p/lXVjVLVGLDJ